# Distance in Fit Api

Tags: google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I'm having trouble obtaining distance traveled using Google Fit Api. I used a similar approach for pedometer and it worked. It just says listener registered.

Most of the code is from the Github sample.

What could be wrong?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public static final String TAG = "BasicSensorsApi";
private static final int REQUEST_OAUTH = 1;
private OnDataPointListener mListener;
private static final String AUTH_PENDING = "auth_state_pending";
private boolean authInProgress = false;

TextView dispSteps;
long numSteps;

private GoogleApiClient mClient = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        authInProgress = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(AUTH_PENDING);
    }

    dispSteps=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.dispStepsTV);
    numSteps=0;

    buildFitnessClient();

}

private void updateDispSteps(final int update) {

    numSteps+=update;

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            dispSteps.setText( String.valueOf(numSteps));
        }
    });
}

private void buildFitnessClient() {
    // Create the Google API Client
    mClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Fitness.API)
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_LOCATION_READ_WRITE))
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ_WRITE))
            .addConnectionCallbacks(
                    new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {

                        @Override
                        public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Connected!!!");

                            Fitness.RecordingApi.subscribe(mClient, DataType.TYPE_DISTANCE_DELTA)
                                    .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onResult(Status status) {
                                            if (status.isSuccess()) {
                                                if (status.getStatusCode()
                                                        == FitnessStatusCodes.SUCCESS_ALREADY_SUBSCRIBED) {
                                                    Log.i(TAG, "Existing subscription for activity detected.");

                                                } else {
                                                    Log.i(TAG, "Successfully subscribed!");
                                                }
                                            } else {
                                                Log.i(TAG, "There was a problem subscribing.");

                                            }
                                        }
                                    });

                            mListener = new OnDataPointListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataPoint(DataPoint dataPoint) {
                                    for (Field field : dataPoint.getDataType().getFields()) {
                                        Value value = dataPoint.getValue(field);
                                        updateDispSteps(value.asInt());
                                        Log.i("BIG BLUE TEXT", value.toString());
                                    }
                                }
                            };

                            SensorRequest req = new SensorRequest.Builder()
                                    .setDataType(DataType.TYPE_DISTANCE_DELTA)
                                    .setSamplingRate(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                    .build();

                            Fitness.SensorsApi.add(mClient, req, mListener)
                                    .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onResult(Status status) {
                                            if (status.isSuccess()) {
                                                Log.i(TAG, "Listener registered!");
                                            } else {
                                                Log.i(TAG, "Listener not registered.");
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
                            if (i == GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_NETWORK_LOST) {
                                Log.i(TAG, "Connection lost.  Cause: Network Lost.");
                            } else if (i == GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_SERVICE_DISCONNECTED) {
                                Log.i(TAG, "Connection lost.  Reason: Service Disconnected");
                            }
                        }
                    }
            )
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(
                    new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                        // Called whenever the API client fails to connect.
                        @Override
                        public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed. Cause: " + result.toString());
                            if (!result.hasResolution()) {
                                // Show the localized error dialog
                                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(),
                                        MainActivity.this, 0).show();
                                return;
                            }
                            if (!authInProgress) {
                                try {
                                    Log.i(TAG, "Attempting to resolve failed connection");
                                    authInProgress = true;
                                    result.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this,
                                            REQUEST_OAUTH);
                                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                                    Log.e(TAG,
                                            "Exception while starting resolution activity", e);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
            )
            .build();
}
```

PS: This is my first question at stackoverflow :P

Comment: if you are able to get step count then u mat convert it into length. Approximately 1300 steps equals 1 Km

Answer (score 1):

```
I think sensor api is used to calculate distance and other values, recoding is for storing them.I used the sensor api and it works for me.

private void buildFitnessClient() {
   if (mClient == null && checkPermissions()) {
       mClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                  .addApi(Fitness.SENSORS_API)
                  .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_LOCATION_READ))
                  .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ_WRITE))....}}


private void findDistDataSrc() {
 Fitness.SensorsApi.findDataSources(mClient, new DataSourcesRequest.Builder()
 // At least one datatype must be specified.
 .setDataTypes(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE,
  DataType.TYPE_DISTANCE_DELTA)
   // Can specify whether data type is raw or derived.
  .setDataSourceTypes(DataSource.TYPE_RAW, DataSource.TYPE_DERIVED)
                .build())
  .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DataSourcesResult>() {
  @Override
  public void onResult(DataSourcesResult dataSourcesResult) {
   //Log.i(TAG, "Result: " + dataSourcesResult.getStatus().toString());
   for (DataSource dataSource : dataSourcesResult.getDataSources()) {
    //Log.i(TAG, "Data source found: " + dataSource.toString());
  //Log.i(TAG, "Data Source type: " + dataSource.getDataType().getName());
 final DataType dataType = dataSource.getDataType();
    if ((dataType.equals(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE) || dataType.equals(DataType.TYPE_DISTANCE_DELTA)) && mListener == null) {
     Log.i(TAG, "Data source for " + dataType.toString() + " found!  Registering.");
..........}
```